# Hibernate 5 import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm working on a maven project in eclipse and I got a error for my hibernate imports. Here are my maven xml file and the java file:

pom.xml (some jboss and tomcat dependencies omitted for relevance)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
   <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring and Transactions -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring ORM support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
package config;

//some imports omitted for relevance 

//these two imports give me "org.springframework.orm cannot be resolved"
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "src.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {}
```

Comment: Yes well then apparently the pom is not correct yet or the project is not successfully mavenized, but showing only a snippet makes it impossible to know what might be wrong. Does your eclipse project show a "maven dependencies" ? Is the spring-orm in there?

Comment: yes it's there. sorry should I include the whole pom?

Comment: Did you try a "maven -> update project" in eclipse ?

Comment: I just did, didn't solve it.

Comment: As show here https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.3.2.RELEASE this dependency contains the package you need. And spring-orm will get by dependency the other sping (jdbc, tx) so you don't to add them explicitly

Comment: try a maven install maybe it is an eclipse issue, not a maven issue.

Comment: use `mvn dependency:tree` and show the output. Only adding a snippet of the pom isn't going to help.